# A generic error occurred

Tags: asp.net

A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException:
 A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 69: 
Line 70:             // Save Thumbnail Image
Line 71:             bmpResized.Save(strPath, fmtImageFormat);
Line 72:             // Save big Images
Line 73:             bmpBigResized.Save(strBigPath, fmtBigImageFormat);
```

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Properties pro = (Properties)e.Row.DataItem;

            HtmlImage imgThumbnail = (HtmlImage)e.Row.FindControl("imgThumbnail");
            //imgThumbnail.Src = ("~/images/Desert.jpg");
            byte[] bitimg = pro.Image1;
            System.Drawing.Image img = byteArrayToImage(bitimg);
            System.Drawing.Image imgBig = byteArrayToImage(bitimg);

Answer (score 0):

The classes in the [`System.Drawing` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) are not supported on ASP.NET:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.

Use [Windows Imaging Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @DeepakPandey - No. I will not.